# I caught myself in the middle of a phishing scam

Tags: virus, phishing, scam

I got caught up in a phishing scam where I conducted an automated interview with emails that appeared legitimate from real people within my college.

I did respond to multiple emails and the only personal information I provided was my email (which they had), my name (which they had), my physical address and my cell phone.

I am not sure any of this is something they couldn't locate anyway. I realized it was a scam when they sent me money to deposit to my account right away for equipment I needed to purchase for the job which they had me look up using specific names and model numbers.

Once I provided the total to purchase the equipment, they sent me a check. I did not download the document but I did open view it in the gmail browser.

My question is do I need to be worried about anything?

I already reported it as phishing in gmail and to my university. I've also run the virus scan on my computer. I changed my google account password. I am not tech savvy and not incredibly educated on this matter so I wanted some opinions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's likely just a fake check scam.  It's always possible it's layered with something more (ransomware, etc) but if people fall for the fake check scam enough the scammer probably doesn't feel the need to do more than that.